# Add class to the clicked button on nodeList in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have list of `button` elements and I want add a class to each when clicked on and remove the class from all other buttons. How I can do this in pure Javascript?

```
<button>btn1</button>
<button>btn2</button>
<button>btn3</button>
<button>btn4</button>
<button>btn5</button>
```

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll("button");

el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  el.classList.remove("toggle");
  this.classList.add("toggle");
});
```

Comment: As you state, `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList, so you need to loop through all the nodes it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the button list two times. The first time to add the **event listener** to **each button**. And the second time when a button is **clicked**.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var cN = "toggle";

function change(el, cN) {
  [].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
    if (btn.className === cN) {
      btn.classList.remove(cN);
    }
  });
  el.classList.add(cN);
}

[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    change(this, cN);
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
}
.toggle {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>btn1</button>
  <button>btn2</button>
  <button>btn3</button>
  <button>btn4</button>
  <button>btn5</button>
</div>
```